# Why is there an API limit on native libraries?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

While looking for a native key/value storage library to use into an Android application, I tried to use [**hsearch**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/hcreate), but when trying to deploy on my "old" phone (API 23), I got an error: "undefined reference to 'hcreate'".

Looking into **search.h** with Android Studio, I found out that these functions can only be used with API levels higher than or equal to 28 (declarations are protected by `#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 28`) in search.h.

Android API 28 was released in August, 2018, and I believe that **hsearch** is older than that, so the question is: why is there such a high API limit on **hsearch** functions?

Comment: It sure is older than that. I released a version of it in 1987.

Comment: Probably only the responsible developers at Google can answer the _"why"_ definitively. But keep in mind that Android has its own libc implementation (Bionic). So just because glibc has feature X doesn't automatically mean that it will make its way over to bionic. As for why they didn't backport the feature to older API levels when they _did_ add it to bionic, I don't know. It could have something to do with then having to roll out updates to lots of older devices so that apps linking against bionic dynamically won't break if they use the newly added feature.

Comment: I don't see what backporting has to do with it. `hsearch()` was there in 1982 if not earlier, and commercially available from at least 1987 as per above. The question is really why did they ever omit it? @Michael

Comment: Well, backporting is relevant since `hsearch` _wasn't_ included in bionic from the start. As for why it wasn't included, perhaps they simply felt that it was a necessary feature. Keep in mind that Android originally had no support for native code in third party apps (the first NDK was released a few months after Android Cupcake). So originally the only code that might interface directly against bionic was Android itself. Or perhaps there was no implementation at the time with a license that Google found acceptable?

Comment: Over time they have added more and more of the POSIX functions, but that brings us back to the problem of rolling out the changes to older Android versions (which may involve getting a bunch of manufacturers and operators on-board, who may not be particularly interested in updating the software for a product they released 3+ years ago).

Comment: Exactly my point. Why was it ever omitted? I used it in a production compiler in 1982 that was ported to dozens of platforms without issue. @Michael

Comment: @user207421 I mention some possible reasons in my second comment. But for a definitive answer you would have to contact the people who originally put together bionic. Google _did_ provide some of its reasoning for using bionic at Google I/O back in 2008:
_"Custom libc implementation, optimized for embedded use.
Why build a custom libc library?
- License: we want to keep GPL out of user-space.
- Size: will load in each process, so it needs to be small.
- Fast: limited CPU power means we need to be fast"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Probably only the responsible developers at Google can answer the "why" definitively.

that'll be me :-)

historically, as you said, bionic was basically "just enough libc to build dalvik". during the dalvik to ART transition i worked on ART and spent enough time fixing libc issues that -- when the need to add 64-bit support arose -- i ended up owning libc instead.

you can see [Android bionic status](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md) both what's happened since the earliest days i was involved with bionic to now, and "what's left". specifically there's actually quite a small list of "stuff we definitely won't add" now, and we try to ensure that's always explained there at the top of that page.

if you look at that page, you'll notice that L -- which is when i basically started working full-time on libc -- was where most of the missing stuff appeared. so in the specific case of <search.h> the question remains "why were these added in API 28 rather than API 21?". the answer to that, as i recall is basically a combination of (a) i don't think we'd ever seen any code using these functions at that point and (b) they look like they ought to be deprecated. the non-`_r` forms are not suitable for use from library code, for example, because they operate on a single global table.

at some point someone came along with third-party code that used it, and i held my nose and added it. part of me still wonders whether we should have only added the `_r` variants, but since C is just one big foot-gun anyway, i felt like the positive value of "it just works" outweighed the negative value of "almost no code should use this, and there's no good way for us to help you catch your mistake".

> just because glibc has feature X doesn't automatically mean that it will make its way over to bionic

we do try to keep track of what glibc adds, to see if there's anything useful going in, but in terms of portability iOS is more relevant to most Android developers. (the conflict between the glibc `qsort_r` and the iOS `qsort_r` is why Android still doesn't have either, for example!)

> As for why they didn't backport the feature to older API levels when they did add it to bionic, I don't know.

none of these cases were security issues, so they'd be ineligible for going into the minor updates.

in some cases, we do actually have inline versions of functions in the headers for targeting old API levels. for example: [termios_inlines.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/bits/termios_inlines.h)

---

getting back to this specific case, the hcreate/hsearch/hdestroy functions are small and simple, so if you want them, you can always include them in your code directly. here's the current ones used in Android (from FreeBSD): [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/upstream-freebsd/lib/libc/stdlib/). but remember that you also have libc++ available, so std::map and friends are trivially available and usually a better choice. (this was one reason why the demand didn't arise for so long.)